# Laravel grab database row by value instead of id

Tags: laravel

I'm fairly new to Laravel, I have an MySQL database table that looks like this...

```
id  | name  | email
------------------------------
23  | john  | john@example.com
77  | jane  | jane@example.com
```

I am trying to delete the row with the email address jane@example.com, I can select the row directly like this...

```
$deleteimage = Image::find(77);
$deleteimage ->delete();
```

But how can I select the row by the email address instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eloquent comes with a full query builder, using the same syntax as the Laravel `DB` query builder. So you can delete all the rows with a certain e-mail address like this:

```
Image::where('email', 'john@example.com')->delete();
```

You can explore all the [functions provided by the Eloquent query builder](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) in the API documentation. There are lots of things in Laravel that is not documented in the normal manual.